# When I install Laravel/Passport auth is not working i always get page expired error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I have installed Auth using Make::Auth method. and it worked fine. but when i installed passport i get error saying page expired when trying to login. and login doest not seems to works as expected.

any help may be appreciated.

Comment: try clearing cache and config reset..if still does not work try composer update and then reset auth and a final make:auth again

Comment: add your form code as well

Answer (score 0):

may be it cookies issue for your previous deployment, 
try to clean browser .